# Ember Data Mapping Missing In Newly Created Model Hash

Tags: javascript, model, ember.js, deserialization, ember-data

I have an Ember app tied into a Rails API.

My Model is defined like this:

```
NewsCMS.NewsItem = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  body_html: DS.attr('string')
});
```

When the app starts up, it successfully pulls in the current models and displays them, however, when I create a new NewsItem, and that item is returned from the API, I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the
>   key body_html but you have no mapping for it

The model is successfully persisted to the Rails API, so the problem definitely lies in the deserialisation of the newly created object, however using breakpoints.

If I compare the structure of the initial model hashes returned by the rails API's index action and the single model hash returned by its create action, they are identical, so why is Ember choking on the newly created model, but dealing with the initial, persisted models without problem?

Looking at where the exception originates, I can see it's here:

```
if (!sideloadedType) {
        sideloadedType = this.sideloadMapping.get(prop);

        if (typeof sideloadedType === 'string') {
          sideloadedType = get(Ember.lookup, sideloadedType);
        }

        Ember.assert("Your server returned a hash with the key " + prop + " but you have no mapping for it", !!sideloadedType);
      }
```

The stack looks like this:

```
Ember.assert (ember.js:52)
DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.sideload (ember-data.js:6482)
DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.extract (ember-data.js:6424)
superWrapper (ember.js:946)
DS.Adapter.Ember.Object.extend.didCreateRecord (ember-data.js:6730)
DS.RESTAdapter.DS.Adapter.extend.createRecord.ajax.success (ember-data.js:7625)
RunLoop._prev (ember.js:4156)
Ember.handleErrors (ember.js:410)
invoke (ember.js:4154)
tryable (ember.js:4343)
Ember.tryFinally (ember.js:1101)
Ember.run (ember.js:4347)
DS.RESTAdapter.DS.Adapter.extend.createRecord.ajax.success (ember-data.js:7624)
jQuery.Callbacks.fire (jquery.js:1038)
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith (jquery.js:1149)
done (jquery.js:8075)
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (jquery.js:8599)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the API's serialisation of the models. I hadn't hooked up an Active Model Serializer to serialize the Model in a way that Ember expected.

I was returning JSON of the format:

```
{name:"", body:""}
```

When it needed to look like this:

```
[
 { news_item: {
    name: "",
    body: ""}
 }
]
```

So Ember was treating the first attribute it hit as a key describing the type of model it was about to deserialize. When it checked to see what to do with this Model it couldn't find anything mapped to it (because it was an attribute of a Model, not a Model itself).

Comment: I have tried both formats and still receive the same error fwiw